# Got warnings from javac -Xlint:unchecked

Tags: java, generics

I got 2 warnings after trying to use the -Xlint switch. How can I solve these warnings?

```
test:quadrantRDBTemplate mymac$ javac -Xlint:unchecked -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.jar:iucbrf.jar *.java 
QuadrantSystemRDB.java:271: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.HashMap
    argMap.put(xKey, new UniformDistribution(-1, 1));
              ^
QuadrantSystemRDB.java:272: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.HashMap
    argMap.put(yKey, new UniformDistribution(-1, 1));
              ^
2 warnings
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A raw type is a type that could have a type argument, but hasn't got on. For example `Map` (and `HashMap`) can have type parameters `K` and `V` for the types of keys and values, respectively.

So you could specify a `Map<Integer,String>` to indicate that the map contains `Integer` objects as keys and maps them to `String` objects.

If you use simply `Map` then you don't provide that information. Raw types exist mostly for backwards compatibility and there is no reason to use them in new code.

Solution: provide the appropriate types to your `Map`. According to your code, the `V` would be `UniformDistribution` and `K` would be the type of `yKey` and `xKey`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use generics!!
Say your xKey type is String, then declare the argMap as:

```
Map<String, UniformDist> argMap = new HashMap<String, UniformDist>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generics for the `argMap`. I suppose the `QuadrantSystemRDB` is from your code. If it is not you can hardly do anything:)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, that is because you need to declare a List object, say (e.g.), without omitting '<' and '>':

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
```

I tried to declare object in stack without in NetBeans, and NetBeans compiled my code with no error messages. Maybe, things are different with javac compiler.